# excel: generate missing years of year range into one cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, range, vba

I have a script that generates the 'gap' years within a year range (year_start <-> year_end - separate inputs) i.e. for 1997-2002, the script generates the following:
1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002 and displays each result in a new row (under one another)

How do I modify it to display the results into *one* cell (row-by-row basis), with the values separated by a comma? Also, ideally, I should be able to select contents of the entire start (A) and end columns (B), the results should then be generated into column C (matches row amount of A and B).

Script:

```
Dim iYear As Integer, iYearS As Integer, iYearE As Integer, iOffset As Integer
Dim oRangeStart As Range

Set oRangeStart = Range("A1")

iYearS = Range("A1")
iYearE = Range("B1")

For iYear = iYearS To iYearE
    oRangeStart.Offset(iOffset, 0).Value = iYear
    iOffset = iOffset + 1
Next
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puts the comma-separated string in column C for any rows that are selected when the macro is run. There is no error-checking to make sure that columns A and B of those rows contain appropriate values:

```
Sub FillYears()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iYear As Integer, iYearS As Integer, iYearE As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim Years As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each cell In Selection.EntireRow.Columns(3).Cells
    iYearS = ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
    iYearE = ws.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
    Years = vbNullString
    For iYear = iYearS To iYearE
        Years = Years & iYear & ","
    Next iYear
    cell.Value = "'" & Left(Years, Len(Years) - 1)
Next cell
End Sub
```

Note that it is necessary to precede the string in Column C with a single-quote to force it to be text. Otherwise Excel helpfully assumes, at least in the US version, that you meant them to be thousands separators and changes them to every three spaces. I never noticed that before!